# how to verify $\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}=\frac{\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x))}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How would I verifty the following trig identity?

> $$
> \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}=\frac{\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}
> $$

I am not sure how to start.

Comment: start with the right side and use the identity $1=\sin^2 x + \cos ^2 x$ and $\tan x= {\sin x \over \cos x}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}=\frac{\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2 x}}{\frac{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2x}}=$$
$$=\frac{\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}=\tan(2x),$$

$$\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}=\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}=\frac{\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}}{1-\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}}$$ and you are at one millimeter from the solution.

Comment: I agree that this is the same as @Roman83's answer. Anyway the transformation in this direction is even more self-solving.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}=\frac{\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\sec^2(x)}{\sec^2(x)}\cdot\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}=\frac{\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\tan(x)}{\sec^2(x)\left(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)\right)}=\frac{\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}$$

Now, use $\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$:

$$\sec^2(x)\left(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)\right)=\cos^2(x)\sec^2(x)-\sin^2(x)\sec^2(x)=$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\right)^2\cos^2(x)-\left(\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\right)^2\sin^2(x)=1-\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=1-\tan^2(x)$$

So, we can conclude:

$$\frac{\tan(x)}{\sec^2(x)\left(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)\right)}=\frac{\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}$$